# Pthreads: How to make thread safe if only allowed to use mutex on one line of code

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads, mutex

I have an assignment where 4 threads go into a "cave" and take out a percentage of pearls. When the cave runs out of pearls, the threads should stop. No two pirates should "enter the cave" at the same time.

My original solution worked fine, but included about 4 lines of code within the mutex. My professor says I am supposed to only lock a single line of code (the line of code where the pearls are taken out of the cave by a thread). However, when I change my code to only protect this one line of code, the code no longer works. My print statements have incorrect values, and my totals are wrong

Is there any way to lock this line only:

```
cavePearls -= pearlsToGrab;
```

And none of the others?

From what I can tell, I have to lock more than one line, or I won't be able to print out the correct data.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NUM_PIRATE_THREADS 4 /* number of pirate threads to run */
#define OPEN_SESAME 0 /* single bit value representation of password */
#define OPEN_WATERMELON 1 /* single bit value representation of password */
#define SLEEP_TIME 2 /* time for thread to sleep after execution */

/* percent value for "open, sesame" */
const double OPEN_SESAME_PERCENTAGE = 0.10;

/* percent value for "open, watermelon" */
const double OPEN_WATERMELON_PERCENTAGE = 0.15;

/* array of pirate threads */
static pthread_t *thread_handles;

/* pirate thread function */
void *pirate(void* rank);

/* total number of items in resource (pearls in the cave) */
static double cavePearls = 1000.00;

/* array to store the number of pearls garnered by each pirate */
int piratesBooty[NUM_PIRATE_THREADS];

/* main function */
int main() {

    /* alert user pirate threads are about to begin consuming pearls */
    printf("\nAvast matey, we are a'comin' fer yee pearls!!\n\n");

    /* index variable for pirate threads */
    long threadIndex;

    /* char variable for pirate thread labeling (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ...) */
    char alphaForPirate = 'A';

    /* create and allocate memory for thread_handles array */
    thread_handles = (pthread_t*)malloc(NUM_PIRATE_THREADS*sizeof(pthread_t));

    /* create and run pirate threads...YAR!*/
    for (threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < NUM_PIRATE_THREADS; ++threadIndex) {
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[threadIndex], NULL,
                       pirate, (void*)threadIndex);
    }

    /* join pirate threads...AVAST MATEY!*/
    for (threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < NUM_PIRATE_THREADS; ++threadIndex) {
        pthread_join(thread_handles[threadIndex], NULL);
    }

    /* update your final cave pearl number to a whole integer value */
    cavePearls = ceil(cavePearls);

    /* display pearl data after pirate thread(s) execution */
    printf("\nYar!! The cave be empty!!\n\n");
    for (threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < NUM_PIRATE_THREADS; ++threadIndex){
        printf("Pirate %c got %d pearls\n",
               alphaForPirate, piratesBooty[threadIndex]);
        alphaForPirate++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* free memory */
    free(thread_handles);

    return 0;
} /* end of main() */

void *pirate(void* rank) {

    /* amount of pearls pirate thread(s) may take during current entry to cave */
    static double pearlsToGrab = 0;

    /* variables to output pirate thread(s) pearl consumption */
    char alphaForPirate = 'A';
    int piratePercentage;

    /* label pirate thread(s) alphanumerically */
    alphaForPirate += (long)rank;

    while(1) { /* continue execution while pearls remain in cave */
        if (cavePearls < 1) /* cave has been emptied, pirate thread(s) should stop */
            return 0;

        /* identify which pirate thread you are currently executing */
        long my_rank = (long)rank;

        /* if pirate thread is even: "Open, sesame" pirate */
        if (my_rank % 2 == OPEN_SESAME) {
            piratePercentage = (OPEN_SESAME_PERCENTAGE * 100);
            pearlsToGrab = ceil(cavePearls * OPEN_SESAME_PERCENTAGE);

            /*****************************/
            /* CRITICAL SECTION LOCKED */
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            cavePearls -= pearlsToGrab;
            piratesBooty[my_rank] += pearlsToGrab;
            /* CRITICAL SECTION UNLOCKED */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            /*****************************/

            printf("Pirate %c gets %.0f of the pearls, %d percent of %.0f pearls available in cave\n",
                   alphaForPirate, pearlsToGrab, piratePercentage, (cavePearls + pearlsToGrab));
        }
        /* if pirate thread is odd: "Open, watermelon" pirate */
        else if (my_rank % 2 == OPEN_WATERMELON){
            piratePercentage = (OPEN_WATERMELON_PERCENTAGE * 100);
            pearlsToGrab = ceil(cavePearls * OPEN_WATERMELON_PERCENTAGE);

            /*****************************/
            /* CRITICAL SECTION LOCKED */
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            cavePearls -= pearlsToGrab;
            piratesBooty[my_rank] += pearlsToGrab;
            /* CRITICAL SECTION UNLOCKED */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            /*****************************/

            printf("Pirate %c gets %.0f of the pearls, %d percent of %.0f pearls available in cave\n",
                   alphaForPirate, pearlsToGrab, piratePercentage, (cavePearls + pearlsToGrab));
        }

        /* make pirate thread(s) sleep for SLEEP_TIME seconds */
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

    } /* end of while-loop */

    /* have pirate thread(s) terminate */
    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}
```

UPDATE:

I've updated my code to include the single line in my mutex. It almost worked, but I'm getting a race condition as follows:

Pirate B gets 135 of the pearls, 15% of 900 pearls available in cave
Pirate A gets 100 of the pearls, 10% of 1000 pearls available in cave
Pirate C gets 77 of the pearls, 10% of 765 pearls available in cave
Pirate D gets 115 of the pearls, 15% of 765 pearls available in cave

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NUM_PIRATE_THREADS 4 /* number of pirate threads to run */
#define OPEN_SESAME 0 /* single bit value representation of password */
#define OPEN_WATERMELON 1 /* single bit value representation of password */
#define SLEEP_TIME 2 /* time for thread to sleep after execution */

/* percent value for "open, sesame" */
const double OPEN_SESAME_PERCENTAGE = 0.10;

/* percent value for "open, watermelon" */
const double OPEN_WATERMELON_PERCENTAGE = 0.15;

struct PirateBag {
    char alphaForPirate;
    double caveTotal;
    double currentPearlsToTake;
    double takePercentage;
};

/* pirate thread function */
void *pirate(void* rank);

/* pirate thread pearl removal and update function */
double executeRemoval(int *piratesBooty, struct PirateBag *piratesBag, const long pirate_rank, const double takePercentage, const double cavePearls);

/* total number of items in resource (pearls in the cave) */
static double cavePearls = 1000.00;

/* mutual exlusion lock; mutual exclusion considered in this version */
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

/* array of pirate threads */
static pthread_t *thread_handles;

/* array to store the number of pearls garnered by each pirate */
int piratesBooty[NUM_PIRATE_THREADS];

/* array to store current pearls being retrieved from cave by pirate thread */
struct PirateBag piratesBag[NUM_PIRATE_THREADS];

/* main function */
int main() {

    /* alert user pirate threads are about to begin consuming pearls */
    printf("\nAvast matey, we are a'comin' fer yee pearls!!\n\n");

    /* index variable for pirate threads */
    long threadIndex;

    /* char variable for pirate thread labeling (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ...) */
    char alphaForPirate = 'A';

    /* create and allocate memory for thread_handles array */
    thread_handles = (pthread_t*)malloc(NUM_PIRATE_THREADS*sizeof(pthread_t));

    /* create and run pirate threads...YAR!*/
    for (threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < NUM_PIRATE_THREADS; ++threadIndex) {
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[threadIndex], NULL,
                       pirate, (void*)threadIndex);
    }

    /* join pirate threads...AVAST MATEY!*/
    for (threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < NUM_PIRATE_THREADS; ++threadIndex) {
        pthread_join(thread_handles[threadIndex], NULL);
    }

    /* update your final cave pearl number to a whole integer value */
    cavePearls = ceil(cavePearls);

    /* display pearl data after pirate thread execution */
    printf("\nYar!! The cave be empty!!\n\n");
    for (threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < NUM_PIRATE_THREADS; ++threadIndex){
        printf("Pirate %c got %d pearls\n",
               alphaForPirate, piratesBooty[threadIndex]);
        alphaForPirate++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* free memory */
    free(thread_handles);

    return 0;
} /* end of main() */

/* pirate thread function */
void *pirate(void* rank) {

    /* amount of pearls pirate thread may take during current entry to cave */
    double pearlsToGrab = 0;

    while(1) { /* continue execution while pearls remain in cave */
        if (cavePearls < 1) /* cave has been emptied, pirate thread should stop */
            return 0;

        /* identify which pirate thread you are currently executing */
        long my_rank = (long)rank;

        /* if pirate thread is even: "Open, sesame" pirate */
        if (my_rank % 2 == OPEN_SESAME) {

            /*****************************/
            /* CRITICAL SECTION LOCKED */
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

            cavePearls -= executeRemoval(piratesBooty, piratesBag, my_rank, OPEN_SESAME_PERCENTAGE, cavePearls);

            /* CRITICAL SECTION UNLOCKED */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            /*****************************/
        }
        /* if pirate thread is odd: "Open, watermelon" pirate */
        else if (my_rank % 2 == OPEN_WATERMELON){

            /*****************************/
            /* CRITICAL SECTION LOCKED */
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

            cavePearls -= executeRemoval(piratesBooty, piratesBag, my_rank, OPEN_WATERMELON_PERCENTAGE, cavePearls);

            /* CRITICAL SECTION UNLOCKED */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            /*****************************/
        }

        /* print pirate thread data for current entry into the cave */
        printf("Pirate %c gets %d of the pearls, %.f%% of %.0f pearls available in cave\n",
               piratesBag[my_rank].alphaForPirate, (int)piratesBag[my_rank].currentPearlsToTake,
               piratesBag[my_rank].takePercentage, piratesBag[my_rank].caveTotal);

        /* make pirate thread sleep for SLEEP_TIME seconds */
        //sleep(SLEEP_TIME);

    } /* end of while-loop */

    /* have pirate thread(s) terminate */
    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}

/* pirate thread pearl removal and collection update function */
double executeRemoval(int *piratesBooty, struct PirateBag *piratesBag, const long pirate_rank, const double takePercentage, const double cavePearls) {
    piratesBooty[pirate_rank] += ceil(cavePearls * takePercentage);
    piratesBag[pirate_rank].alphaForPirate = (pirate_rank + 'A');
    piratesBag[pirate_rank].caveTotal = cavePearls;
    piratesBag[pirate_rank].currentPearlsToTake = ceil(cavePearls * takePercentage);
    piratesBag[pirate_rank].takePercentage = (takePercentage * 100);

    return ceil(cavePearls * takePercentage);
}
```

Comment: are print statements part of the assignment? The _only_ things that needs to go in the critical section are the data that is shared between threads. `cavePearls` certainly is.. any time you access `cavePearls` outside of hte critical section you're subject to race conditions.

Comment: `alphaForPirate += (long)rank;` looks wrong ,, I think you want to change that to `alphaForPirate += *((long*)rank);`, same with `long my_rank`. Why is `pearlsToGrab` static? Making that local to the `priate` function will eliminate all the race conditions you currently have on that. Unless I'm missing it `pearlsToGrab` isn't used outside of the `pirate` function. Each thread gets its own stack and therefore its own stack variables. Making that static means all the threads will share one of them.

Comment: `pearlsToGrab` can't be used outside the function due to its scope. I haven't gone through your code in detail, but it just makes sense from a top level that each pirate should calculate his own `pearlsToGrab`. Is that somehow dependent on the other pirates? If not, make it local to the `pirate` function.

Comment: FYI: The pirate function is declared as void, therefore, you can't return zero or anything else. `return 0;` should just be `return;`

Comment: I went ahead and changed my return 0; to just return; I also made the changes to alphaForPirate and my_rank. However, I'm still stuck on how to only lock the mutation of cave pearls, when I need to also reference my current cave pearls amount in my printf ("Pirate thread X took x-many pearls."). I would think the only way to get an accurate read from cavePearls would be to make sure the printf is in the lock too. I thought about perhaps storing the data I need in a 4-cell array so the amount of pearls each pirate collected would only write to their cell. However, it seems "hacky."

Comment: @jwdonahue I believe the preferred method for exiting a `pthread` function is `pthread_exit(NULL)` or simply nothing if you don't want to return a value. You can return a status parameter from the exiting thread to the calling thread via `pthread_join`.

Comment: @DouglasAdolph You can use a local variable to save the result of a shared variable in a critical section, then you can print the local value outside of the critical section and it will be whatever the critical value was when it was locked. Printing to the screen takes a long time, you want critical sections to be as small and simple and fast as possible.. I would generally avoid printing inside a critical section.

Comment: @jwdonahue My system actually complained when I took out the 0. Return 0; works, return; does not. Not sure why. It does look void to me too.

Comment: @jwdonahue Made some changes. The logic seems sound, but I'm getting a race condition. I added my newer version. Thanks!

Comment: @DouglasAdolph, actually I apparently missed that it is declared to return a void*, probably a requirement of the pthreads interface.  Rather than return 0, you should return NULL.  It will read better.

Comment: @DouglasAdolph, what race condition?  I think you just need to declare cavePearls volatile.  You've probably got a thread or two running on different cores.  Declaring `volatile int cavePearls` may be enough to fix it. If not, you'll need to add memory fences and I don't recall off the top of my head how that's done on *nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough to clue you in:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
cavePerls = perlsToPrint = cavePerls - CalculatePerlsToGrab();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
// Print using perlsToPrint value.
```

NOTE: `CalculatePerlsToGrab()` could be `CalcStatsAndReturnPerlsToGrab(&whatever,...)`

Comment: Not going to supply you with a copy & past answer, but essentially, you need to move all the calculations involving cavePerls to a single line. To do that you put them in a function that is called to update cavePerls. Said function can have side effects, such as calculating the other stats you want to report.  I would wrap those in a struct and pass the address to that struct to the calculation function. Then you have a snapshot of the data as it was while you held the lock.